# iOS override hardware volume buttons (Same as Zello)

Tags: ios, volume

I am currently working on a PTT (push-to-talk) app.
I am trying to use to hardware volume buttons to start/stop transmission.

All suggested solutions I've seen so far can be narrowed down to two:

1. Using KVO to observe `AVAudioSession` property `outputVolume`.
2. Using private API notification, namely `AVSystemController_SystemVolumeDidChangeNotification` and since iOS 15.0 - `SystemVolumeDidChange`.

Without getting into the pros and cons of each solution, they both have one thing in common - they are volume based, which raises several problems.

1. Pressing volume buttons changes system volume. Although this can be fixed by resetting system volume, it's not a pretty solution.
2. There is no way to discern between volume changes coming from hardware buttons, and volume changes coming from command center for instance, therefore buttons usage us limited to when app is in the foreground and active.
3. When user presses volume button there is a short delay between first volume change event, and the consecutive events that follows, which makes it difficult to track quick press and release.

I have noticed that Zello app has somehow managed to overcome those issues, as they enable the usage of volume buttons even when device is closed or when command center is open - without any interference to the system volume. In addition changing volume from command center has not effect.

Does anyone have any idea as to how to achieve such a behavior?

Comment: https://support.zello.com/hc/en-us/articles/230745867-Can-I-use-volume-key-to-PTT-on-iPhone- Zello removed this functionality

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Warning Private API usage follows. You MUST have some special circumstances that may allow you to get through AppStore Review.**

Take look at [Explore the iOS SDK and use undocumented APIs](https://sudonull.com/post/138905-Explore-the-iOS-SDK-and-use-undocumented-APIs) from 2012.

To summarise, you need to call the private method `- [UIApplication setWantsVolumeButtonEvents:YES]` to enable the following notifications:

- `_UIApplicationVolumeUpButtonDownNotification`
- `_UIApplicationVolumeUpButtonUpNotification`
- `_UIApplicationVolumeDownButtonDownNotification`
- `_UIApplicationVolumeDownButtonUpNotification`

In Swift this can be enabled with something like:

```swift
@objc public protocol UIApplicationPrivate {
    @objc func setWantsVolumeButtonEvents(_:Bool)
}

class VolumeButtonsManager {
    private static var observer: NSObjectProtocol?

    static func setup(with application: UIApplication) {
        observer = NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: nil,
                                                          object: nil,
                                                          queue: nil,
                                                          using: handleEvent)
        
        let application = unsafeBitCast(application, to:UIApplicationPrivate.self)
        application.setWantsVolumeButtonEvents(true)
    }

    private static func handleEvent(_ notification: Notification) {
        switch notification.name.rawValue {
        case "_UIApplicationVolumeUpButtonDownNotification": print("Volume Up Button Down")
        case "_UIApplicationVolumeUpButtonUpNotification": print("Volume Up Button Up")
        case "_UIApplicationVolumeDownButtonDownNotification": print("Volume Down Button Down")
        case "_UIApplicationVolumeDownButtonUpNotification": print("Volume Down Button Up")
        default: break
        }
    }
}
```

`UIApplicationPrivate` via [Silencing a warning for explicitly constructed selector](https://forums.swift.org/t/silencing-a-warning-for-explicitly-constructed-selector/41084).

Comment: This method seems no longer working on iOS 17.4

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are trying to do will result in an app store rejection at the review process as Apple mention it in [the App Store Review Guidelines paragraph 2.5.9](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#software-requirementshttps://)

> Apps that alter or disable the functions of standard switches, such as the Volume Up/Down and Ring/Silent switches, or other native user interface elements or behaviors will be rejected. For example, apps should not block links out to other apps or other features that users would expect to work a certain way. Learn more about proper handling

Comment: With AppStore we can deal later. We might have some special circumstances that may allow us to get through. My question is from a technical POV - how and if it is possible to achieve said behavior.